# Outlook 2013 API adding contacts to a programmatically created contact group

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2013

I'm currently working on playing around with the API for 2013 Outlook in C# and was in the process of creating a Contact Group (datalist) when I ran into an odd issue.

I was able to create a contact group okay using the following code, however after creation it appears that the contact group contains no contacts.

However, upon inspection when creating the group and adding the contacts (filter of must have a email address), I can see the contacts being stored in the display of the contact group prior to it being saved.

```
        Outlook.DistListItem distList = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olDistributionListItem) as Outlook.DistListItem;
        distList.Subject = "TEST GROUP";
        // grab all addresses such that primary email is not an empty string
        string filter = "[Email1Address] <> ''";
        // grab the table of users
        Outlook.Table table = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).GetTable(filter, Outlook.OlTableContents.olUserItems);
        // addingin email address so table must have column to represent this
        table.Columns.Add("Email1Address");
        while (!table.EndOfTable)
        {
            Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow();
            if (nextRow["Email1Address"] == null)
            {
                // no more addresses left to process.
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // create a recipient based upon information in our table
                Outlook.Recipient recipient = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(nextRow["Email1Address"].ToString());
                // ensure recipient is valid by checking our address book for resolution
                recipient.Resolve();
                MessageBox.Show(recipient.ToString() + "\nEOT: " + table.EndOfTable);
                distList.AddMember(recipient);
            }
        }
        // name the list?
        distList.DLName = "Testing addin";
        // save the list
        distList.Save();
```

When attempting to send an email to this contact group I am prompted with the following error message:

> The contact group(s) this message is addressed to must contain at least one recipient.

Comment: Are you sure Recipient.Resolve() returns true?

Comment: Yes, as I'm taking them directly from my contacts book I had assumed they would have resolved correctly, however I checked on all entries and each one was returning true.